# DependencyPropety call PropertyChangedCallback on ReactiveList.Add()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created my own `ComboBox` according to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF) article:

```
public partial class MultiSelectComboBox : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource",
             typeof(IList),
             typeof(MultiSelectComboBox),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                 new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems",
            typeof(IList),
            typeof(MultiSelectComboBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And Used in One of my Views:

```
<CustomControls:MultiSelectComboBox x:Name="Versions"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}"
                SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedVersions}">
```

The propertieces that I have binded are [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) `ReactiveList<t>`:

```
    private IReactiveList<IVersion> selectedVersions;
    private IReactiveList<IVersion> versions;

    public IReactiveList<IVersion> Versions
    {
        get { return this.versions; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.versions, value); }
    }

    public IReactiveList<IVersion> SelectedVersions
    {
        get { return this.selectedVersions; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.selectedVersions, value); }
    }
```

So after I add some elements to this lists it don't refresh it's content (it works when I'm assigning `new ReactiveList`), I get why, it is because I'm not using `ObservableCollection<T>` as type of my DP in `MultiSelectComboBox` But after changing `IList` to `ObservableCollection<Object>` I get cast exception (can't cast `IReactiveList<IVersion>` to `ObservableCollection<Object>`), I don't want to use `ObservableCollection<IVersion>` because I want to use it in other projects to bind other types than `IVersion`. Is there any good way to catch Add/Remove/Clear events?

In addition I can say that also after `ItemsSource.Add(A)` i have tried to call `this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ItemsSource));` and it didn't work.

Comment: You have to attach and detach a `CollectionChanged` handler method in `OnItemsSourceChanged` and probably also in `OnSelectedItemsChanged`, as shown in the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39566873/1136211) in case you want to derive directly from ItemsControl.